# Import excel column in Sybase table

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

I need to import a column from excel sheet into a **Sybase ASE** table.
The column is a varchar value.

Could you please help me with a solution?

/Niraj

Answer (score 0):

Export the data into a CSV file, and import it into the database using the BCP utility.

More on how to use the BCP utility can be found here:

[Sybase ASE Docs - BCP Utility](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/X14951.htm)